# how to run all files from a script folder using sql query

Tags: sql-server, ssms

In the directory 'C:\scripts' I am having script files in '.sql' format.How to execute all these files at the time using sql query from my SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO.

Comment: hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the tour here: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Open them all in SSMS and run them one by one?

Comment: mordack -Please tell once if know answer

Answer (score 1):

If this linked post contains the info you need then I suggest marking your post as duplicate of the linked one: [Run all SQL files in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583517/run-all-sql-files-in-a-directory)

Otherwise, check if this helps: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/execute-sql-scripts-batch.aspx

Answer (score 0):

make a batch file with `anyname.bat` and save it in the same directory, save it and run it.
this sample of mysql

```
@ECHO OFF

ECHO Running scripts
FOR %%i IN (*.sql) DO mysql -uroot -proot databasename< %%i

ECHO Finished!
pause
```

Comment: please give query for sql

Comment: sql is Structured Query Language, it is used to query your database not to run `.sql` files placed somewhere in your system. what is the need to do so?