# How to run SQL files in a directory in order by file name in PSQL

Tags: sql, bash, postgresql, psql

Sort of like this question: [Run all SQL files in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583517/run-all-sql-files-in-a-directory)

I have files like: `V1__some_migration.sql`, `V2__some_other_one.sql`, etc

I was wondering how I could loop through and import these in some bash script based on the file name (bonus points if you know a way that works both on UNIX [OS X] and Linux [Ubuntu])

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loop through:

```
YOUR_DIR="/path/to/your/directory"
for file in $YOUR_DIR/*; do
    psql <insert your options here> "${file}"
done
```

Comment: Maybe import is a bad word for it? We have a very small, not mission critical, backend service that needs migrations. The migrations are fairly simple but wanted an easy way loop through and import the migrations in a post deploy type hook. The SQL files themselves are written always as "if not exists" so they should be safe to run many times over.

Comment: About to try it! Thank you for such a fast response!

Comment: Using variable `PATH` is not very good idea. Also it will fail if file names contains spaces.

Comment: Oh, really, I didn't noticed :)
No one should use spaces in Unix filenames.
If fact, simple shell expansion has files already sorted.
So ls | sort may be just *. It works with spaces.