# How to create an SSIS Package that will run a list of T-SQL queries located in a specific folder?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

I am using `SQL Server 2012` and I need to create an `SSIS` package that will run a list of `T-SQL` queries from a specific folder.

My list of `T-SQL` queries have been named starting with '01 (name of query).sql' and the folder contains a list of 25 queries. I need the task to run these queries
starting with query '01...' to '25...'

Can this be created in an `SSIS` package? If yes, which task should I use?

**Update 1**

I tried the first method suggested by *@Hadi* and the script task throws the following exception

> Error: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

*screenshot of my task in SSDT*

[image]

*Script Task VB code*

```
 <Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute()> _
<System.CLSCompliantAttribute(False)> _
Partial Public Class ScriptMain
 Inherits Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase

 Public Sub Main()

    Using sr As New IO.StreamReader(Dts.Variables("strFilename").Value.ToString)

        Dts.Variables("strQuery").Value = sr.ReadToEnd()
        sr.Close()

    End Using

    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
End Sub

End Class
```

*Variables*

[image]

Comment: Foreach Loop over the files in the folder (Collection > Foreach File Enumerator, choose folder, use *.sql for Files). Create a variable. Assign the file to the variable. Put Execute SQL Task in the loop container. Use the variable as the source of the Execute SQL Task.

Comment: Thanks. I am a bit lost at the "Create a Variable" step! How do I do this?

Comment: Should be an option in the dropdown for New Variable under the Variable Mappings. Or add one from the SSIS>Variables menu first.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain here. I am new to this. I have already created the Variable. How do I "Assign the file to the variable"?

Comment: Ok, I have managed to progress with the Variable issue. Now, when running the package in SSDT, I am getting the following error message:
[Execute SQL Task] Error: An error occurred with the following error message: "Access to the path 'C:\RUN\CleaningQueries' is denied.".
Any ideas on how to turn this around?

Comment: @user3115933 have you tried my suggestion? The links contains much details on that

Comment: @Hadi Not yet as I had already progressed with the comments provided by Jacob H. I will give yours a try tomorrow morning (already very late here!).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## (1) Using Script Task + Execute SQL Task

1. Add a Foreach Loop container
2. Choose the type = File enumerator
3. Select the Folder containing the `.sql` files as Source Directory
4. Select the `Fully qualified` file name option
5. Go To variable mapping Tab, Map the result to a Variable *(Create new one ex: `@[User::strFilename]`)*
6. Create a Variable of Type String `@[User::strQuery]`
7. In the foreach Loop container add a Script Task and Select `@[User::strFilename]` as *ReadOnly Variable* and `@[User::strQuery]` as *ReadWrite Variable*
8. Inside the Script Task Write the following Code *(Choose Visual Basic as Language)*:

   ```
   Try

       Using sr as new IO.StreamReader(Dts.Variables("strFilename").Value.ToString)

           Dts.Variables("strQuery").Value = sr.ReadToEnd()
           sr.Close()

       End Using

       Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success

   Catch ex as exception

       Messagebox.Show(ex.Message)
       Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Failure

   End Try
   ```
9. Add an `Execute SQL Task` linked to the `Script Task`, and Select the ConnectionString property, then choose `SQLSource Type` property = `Variable`
10. Select `@[User::strQuery]` as `SourceVariable`

---

## (2) Using Execute Process Task

Use a foreach loop container  to loop over these files, then use an `Execute process task` to run these queries using `SQLCMD`.

**Additional Information:**

- [SSIS BASICS: Introducing the Foreach Loop Container](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/ssis-basics-introducing-the-foreach-loop-container/)
- [Foreach Loop Container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/foreach-loop-container)
- [Run Transact-SQL Script Files Using sqlcmd](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170572(v=sql.110).aspx)

---

## (3) Using a batch file

Also you can achieve this without SSIS, just using a batch file `.BAT` that you create with notepad:

- [Run all SQL files in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583517/run-all-sql-files-in-a-directory)

Comment: Thanks. I will go through those documentation. I will need to add this package as a step in sql agent job process that will run on a daily basis.

Comment: I think these links will helps you to do that, if you need more details just give me a feedback

Comment: The link "Run Transact-SQL Script Files Using sqlcmd" gives an example where there is a single query. How do I deal with multiple queries in the folder?

Comment: @user3115933 - you will run one file every loop.

Comment: @user3115933 i added a new method, you can check it

Comment: @Hadi Thanks a lot for your efforts! I have just tried your solution (1). I followed each step closely and when I run it in SSDT, I get the following error:
"Error: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."

Comment: @Hadi I have added a screenshot to show the flow. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, check that the variablename is correct. The name is case sensitive

Comment: If it still not working, just provide the Script task full code so it will be more clear

Comment: If it still not working, just provide the Script task full code so it will be more clear

Comment: @Hadi Script Task VB code + Variables Window screenshot added above.

Comment: @user3115933 i think that the problem is with strFilename variable, there is an error reading the path, or the variable doesn't contains a correct value, check that you have assigned the value correctly to `strFilename`. Also you can try a `TRY Catch` block to read the exception. check my code update for more info

Comment: @user3115933 read more about foreach loop container, and how to assign values to variable here: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/ssis-basics-introducing-the-foreach-loop-container/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163531/discussion-between-user3115933-and-hadi).

Answer (score 1):

I upvoted Hadi, as I learned something new.

But this is how I do it with a script task. Dealers choice.

```
//Read SQL to string
System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(Dts.Variables["ForEachFilePathName"].Value);
string sql = sr.ReadToEnd();
sr.Close();

string cstr = Dts.Variables["connString"].Value;
using (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(cstr))
{
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand cmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, conn);

     conn.Open();
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: I forgot the reason I did this and now reading other responses, it is because I really use this as a script component source where I write the results out to the data flow. I converted it to meet your needs.