# SQLCMD command, How to save output into log file

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, cmd, sqlcmd, logfile

The following question has helped me solving the problem of executing multiple SQL Scripts located in file. [Run all SQL files in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583517/run-all-sql-files-in-a-directory)

However, I did not get how to redirect the output into a separate log file. Someone suggested the following script but since I don't understand it, it did not work and I can't find out the error.

```
for %f in (*.sql) do sqlcmd /S <servername> /d <dbname> /E /i "%f" >> sql.log 2>&1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need the output into one common file then you should use the @Abhishek 's answer.

If you need the output into a **separate log file for an each input sql file**
then you can use `-o` parameter of `sqlcmd` command. Your `bat` file could look like this:

```
for %%G in (*.sql) do sqlcmd /S <servername> /d <dbname> -E -i"%%G" -o C:\logs\%%G.log
pause
```

In this case for

> 1.sql
>
> 2.sql

you will get:

> 1.sql.log
>
> 2.sql.log

Comment: You may get the same result via: `for %%G in (*.sql) do (sqlcmd /S <servername> /d <dbname> -E -i "%%G" > C:\logs\%%~nG.log)`  In this case, for `file1.sql` and `file2.sql` you will get `file1.log` and `file2.log`

Answer (score 2):

You are seeking **Command Redirection**.

As per your example -

`for %f in (*.sql) do sqlcmd /S <servername> /d <dbname> /E /i "%f" >> sql.log 2>&1`

once the execution of the sql script is done the output will be redirected to and **appends the command output to the end of file (here sql.log) without deleting the information that is already in the file** (>>) and redirects STDERR (2) into STDOUT handle(1) - `2>&1`

More information [here](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc772622(v=ws.10).aspx).

Comment: I must be missing something, since it does not work for me. I did exactly the stated but no logs are saved in my directory