# Does SQL Server provide a way to load and execute SQL files?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a collection of `.sql` files containing ddl for various database objects.

For example:

1. User.sql
2. Group.sql
3. GroupUser.sql

Is there a way I can use a stored procedure to easily/elegantly load/execute these files in sequence? For example, `GroupUser.sql` depends on the existence of `User` and `Group`, so I need to execute the `.sql` files in the order listed above.

I know I could concatenate the contents of all of the `.sql` scripts above into a stored procedure, but I would prefer to take a more modular approach. I could also put each script into its own stored procedure but I'd rather not clutter the stored procedure collection in my app database with DDL setup scripts.

Comment: below stack answer explains this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583517/run-all-sql-files-in-a-directory

Comment: Strictly speaking, SQL Server doesn't even know what a `.sql` file is, much less what to do with it. The server is only aware of the commands sent to it. Client tools are much more useful for this.

Answer (score 0):

From SSMS, go to the "Query" menu, and select "SQLCMD Mode". Once there, you can run commands like this. I script out stuff like this all the time.

```
use test
go

:r "D:\SomeDataDirectory\SomeSQLFile.sql"
```

EDIT: Didn't see you wanted to do this within a stored procedure. That's a bit of a dicey proposition. Assuming you have permissions to execute it, you could put the same SQLCMD code in calls to [xp_cmdshell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-cmdshell-transact-sql), but in many circumstances that won't be an option for you unless you've got admin-like permissions on the server.