# How to run multiple sqlfiles at once in SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

I have multiple SQL files under a directory which are having sequence numbering in the filename.

**Folder : TableOperation**

```
00_CreateTable.sql
01_InsertTable.sql
02_UpdateTable.sql
03_DropTable.sql
```

How do we run these SQL files(00_..,01_..,02_..,03_..) at once in SSMS?

Comment: What do you mean by "test the files"?

Comment: @Larnu How do we run these sql files(00_..,01_..,02_..,03_..)  at once in SSMS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run all SQL files in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583517/run-all-sql-files-in-a-directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch the query editor to SQLCMD mode

[image]

and run

```
:r 00_CreateTable.sql
:r 01_InsertTable.sql
:r 02_UpdateTable.sql
:r 03_DropTable.sql
```

Comment: :setvar path C:\"some path"

:r $(path)\myfile.sql